# Why does progress bar fail to show while using WebView in Android Studio, using Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm quite new to Android, I'm using Java and Android Studio to display a web page inside my app using Android WebView. I want to show a Progress Bar before the web page loads. I've managed to display the page but the progress does not show, what could be the issue? Please help. Below is my code:

Java File:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class RentalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rentals);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://www.sampleulr.com/page");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:progressDrawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` - it will shows views in linear fashion, in this case whole space will be taken by webview. Use `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @Nitish Thanks for your help, I have tried using `ConstraintLayout` but still it does not show. Could it be an issue in my Java code?

Comment: Set the elevation to the ProgressBar to make sure it's on top of webview in `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @Nitish I have tried that still no success

Comment: Strange , I copied your code in a sample app but it works fine for me. Only difference I did was to use `ConstraintLayout` and loaded google.com as url mentioned in question is not working.

Comment: @Nitish, thanks for your help. Will keep checking what could be the issue.

Comment: Here the code which I tried if it helps - [WebActivity](https://gist.github.com/Nitish-29/5b142428b6efff6eb89777c0e1be54b2) , [xml file](https://gist.github.com/Nitish-29/0b756b4d34bf13e3f93c91c80b55ba02)